# Splitting a string entry into multiple columns by customized "tags"

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time splitting a column into multiple columns by tags preceding each string.

My pandas dataframe looks something like the following:

| year | text |
| --- | --- |
| 2009 | [<h1>Country A, <i>Issue 1, <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <p>Sed nec mi congue, ornare orci ut, feugiat risus, <h1>Country B, <i>Issue 1, <p>lorem ipsum, <p>dolor sit amet, <i>Issue2, <p>whatever blah <p>whichever blah] |
| 2010 | [<h3>Country A, <i>Issue 1, <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <p>Sed nec mi congue, ornare orci ut, feugiat risus, <h3>Country B, <i>Issue 1, <p>lorem ipsum, <p>dolor sit amet, <i>Issue2, <p>whatever blah <p>whichever blah] |

I have three customized tags, <hx>, <i> and <p> which denote the structure of the whole text. x in <hx> stands for some random number that is of no importance, as long as the tag precedes a country name. Under <hx> are <i>s, and each <i> encompasses mutiple <p>s. I want to divide the "text" column into three separate columns which corresponds to each tag, and the resulting dataframe should be in the long format. Multiple paragraphs with <p> tags that belong to the same <i> should be accumulated into a single entry. So what I have in mind as the result is:

| year | country(hx) | issue(i) | body(p) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | Country A | Issue 1 | lorem ipsum...blah |
| 2009 | Country A | Issue 2 | whatever...blah |
| 2009 | Country B | Issue 1 | no matter...blah |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2020 | Country F | Issue 1 | lorem ipsum...blah |
| 2020 | Country F | Issue 2 | lorem ipsum...blah |

Comment: You forgot to post how you attempted to solve this problem.